# Downloaded React App file but don't know how to open the server

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn React and I just downloaded a file for a project i'm working on with a friend. I cannot figure out how to run the terminal properly to show the react application on the local server.

What are the proper command lines to do so?

Comment: Do you only have a single file or an entire folder? You won't be able to run it locally if all you have is one file. Could you show the structure of what your friend gave you?

Comment: I have a "build" file and a "source" file. They seem to have all the files necessary to run, edit and deploy it. I'm more familiar with HTML/CSS so I know that just opening a live server on the HTML file won't accurately reflect any changes

Comment: See the answer below. It should work

Answer (score 1):

In root of project folder. first "npm i" - install all node-modules. npm start  - start project.

Comment: So when I do that I just get the standard "Edit src/App.js" screen, it's like it's not recognizing any of the actual code and it's showing me a blank screen

Comment: can you drop project on git?

Comment: Maybe I'm accessing the root wrong? I open a Mac terminal and go 

ls desktop
cd build
npm i
npm start

Comment: Folder build for use it on hosting. You should write this commands in higher folder, where you have folders: public, build, src

Comment: Here I added it to github https://github.com/OhItsPM/soulbulbs-source

Comment: Would you be able to help me with a step by step on how to open it via the terminal?